# Flutter Converting network image into byteData

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any better way to convert network image to byteData? I am trying to convert network image from firebase url to byteData and here is my code:

```
Future<Uint8List> _loadNetworkImage() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(imageUrl);
      return response.bodyBytes;
    } catch (_) {
      throw "Couldn't resolve network Image.";
    }
  }
```

Currently it takes almost 20+ seconds for a 7mb photo to be converted.

Comment: No, it is the proper way, it is taking time to fetch the image from the internet. Here there maybe two type of problems:
1. Your internet connection is slow.
2. Your server configuration is not so good to deliver the image in less than 20 seconds for a 7 MB of photo.

Comment: I did test the both scenarios before asking. Server is firebase storage and internet speed is good enough download normally takes around 2 max downloading 10mb contents. I wouldn't care if timing was around 10 seconds but 20 seconds is waay to much waiting time.

Comment: Then you can do it in the background because there is no way to decrease the time because it is variable with the image size you have.

Comment: have you solved it ?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Please check my comment to see the solution that I implemented. @RustamUsmanov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it.

```
Future<Uint8List?> _loadNetworkImage(String path) async {
    final completer = Completer<ImageInfo>();
    var img = NetworkImage(path);
    img.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener((info, _) => completer.complete(info)));
    final imageInfo = await completer.future;
    final byteData =
        await imageInfo.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```